Stripe webhooks keep failing in Vercel/Supabase Environment when subscribing
EDIT
The actual problem were not the BAD Requests, but rather that one time payments in stripe do not count as "subscriptions". Therefore, my app broke, since I am not checking for payments, but only subscriptions in the front end.
I am currently building a small SaaS based on this template, and pretty much 100% followed the guide. I am using the same database for development and production.
https://vercel.com/templates/next.js/subscription-starter
I basically only followed the instructions in the repo, and everything worked smoothly.
Locally and on my site, everything worked as it should.
However, today my stripe webhooks all started to fail, when I wanted to subscribe, giving me a 400 Error - Bad Request, with this Info:

Unsupported event type: customer.discount.created (for example)

I checked public and secret keys, and even set a new stripe webhook, with no results. Also my vercel logs only show the Bad request, but no further information.
Potential reasons:
I think i recently changed the Supabase SITE URL in the supabase dashboard, and I now get the following error when developing locally, although I am not sure that those two actually correlate:
[AuthApiError: Invalid Refresh Token: Refresh Token Not Found] {
  __isAuthError: true,
  name: 'AuthApiError',
  status: 400,
  code: undefined
}

I found the issue here: https://github.com/supabase/auth-helpers/issues/436
But since its my first time using supabase and stripe, I am not sure that supabase is the reason the stripe subscriptions are not working.
What would help me:
If anyone ran into the same problem, this would obviously help me the most, but if someone could help me with getting more information from the stripe webhook errors, I believe I would be able to figure the problem out myself. So far I unfortunately have not been able to find a way to get more insights there.

You wrote that customer.discount.created as an "example" of an error message - but is that the actual error message? I note that customer.discount.created is a real event in Stripe so that error-message, taken at face-value, is wrong.

Its from the Webhook Page on Stripe, and the Answer is 400 (Bad Request), and the message "Unsupported event type: customer.discount.created"

What version of the Stripe API is your account configured for?

The newest one - 2024-06-20

This error message was thrown from your Webhook server, not Stripe. I'd recommend checking why your Webhook server doesn't recognise customer.discount.created event or whether this event can be handled.
